# How can I disconnect all the running sessions in opentok iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, opentok

I'm using opentok for voice call/video call.

And connection between user A and user B working fine & good but I have one problem when the time of disconnecting user A's session closed correctly but user B's Session was not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Showing some sample code will be nice. You probably want to call `session.disconnect()` for both user A and user B. Calling `session.disconnect()` for one user will only disconnect that particular user from the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using session.destroy() and publisher.destroy() for disconnecting stream.